# Returning binary body and http headers from an AWS lambda through API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda that needs to return a binary object and some http headers (e.g. content-type) through an api gateway (using lambda integration) OR redirect to another URL. In the binary support examples (e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/) the lambda only returns the (base64 of the) binary object (the image). In my case, I also need to return a status code and http headers (or something equivalent). I struggle with how I can make this work with binary support in api gateway.

The lambda returns a json on this form:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "image/jpeg"
  },
  "body": "/9j/4AAQS...gLDAoKCAwZK",
  "isBase64Encoded": true
}
```

In the integration response I add body mappings for image/jpeg (etc) of the form:

```
$input.json('$.body')
```

And header mapping for 'content-type' like so:

```
integration.response.body.headers['content-type']
```

I've tried many variations of the above, but the result is consistently

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform response
```

How do I transform the json from the lambda into a form that can be converted to binary by the api gateway, with http headers and all? Can I get more debug logging out of the api gateway to show more specific what it is unhappy with?

Is there perhaps a way to get more debug logging out of the api gateway?

Comment: Did you get this working? I have the same challenge...

Comment: No. Sorry. Instead I returned a redirect to another lambda that only returned binary objects. So, several lambdas. Clumsy, but works-

Comment: I did get this working. Works great in fact. As long as you configure the resource as a proxy resource and ensure that your accept mime type matches the Binary Media Types setting in Settings for your API (in api gateway).

Answer (score 2):

I recently got this working after facing a similar problem.

In my case, I was missing two things:

First, I needed to change the list of types AWS will send to the upstream in the "Accept" header"

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types" : [
  "image/jpeg"
]
```

Secondly, I needed to set the Integration Response to "Convert to binary (if needed)":

```
"contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_BINARY"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49393465/6460914) for the details, and sample config.

I also found that I wasn't being patient enough. Whenever I deployed the API, I was checking immediately, instead of waiting a few minutes for the changes to propagate.

Answer (score 1):

I tired returning binary data with base64 encoding, but I couldn't manage to return it from Lambda function through API Gateway.

Therefore, I decided to redirect the URL. I changed the Method Response to 302 and added "Location" Response header. I also deleted response code 200 from Integration Response, selected 302 as response code and mapped `integration.response.body.location` value with `Location` header. My Lambda code returned location of redirect URL in this format:

```
{"location":"www.google.com/"}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to do the same for days, but couldn't find any documentation to back up that it's possible, instead I found this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html

> When converting a text payload to a binary blob, API Gateway assumes that the > text data is a Base64-encoded string and outputs the binary data as a
> Base64-decoded blob. If the conversion fails, it returns a 500 response
> indicating an API configuration error. You do not provide a mapping template
> for such a conversion, although you must enable the passthrough behaviors on
> the API.
>
> When converting a binary payload to a text string, API Gateway always applies > a Base64 encoding on the binary data. You can define a mapping template for
> such a payload, but can only access the Base64-encoded string in the mapping
> template through $input.body, as shown in the following excerpt of an example > mapping template.

which sounds to me that mapping like this is only possible the other way around; what I ended up doing is that just return Base64Encoded binary string and hard code the content-type and cache- control in header mapping; for the complete implementation see my blog post https://mesfinmoges.com/dynamic-image-resizing-using-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-mazon-api-gateway-amazon-cloudfront/